# cannot uninstall tensorflow after pip uninstall/conda remove

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

my environment accidentally installed three versiosn of tensorflow, and i tried to use
 `pip uninstall tensorflow` and `conda remove tensorflow`
to remove all packages.

but when i ran the `conda search tensorflow` in my env, 
it still shows three of them.how can i delete them completely?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `conda search Tensorflow` command looks for available Tensorflow binaries on your conda channels (servers to install from). If you want to list your locally installed packages, run the command `conda list` and look for Tensorflow. If it doesn't appear in the list, you uninstalled it successfully.